# Curious about how to work out a formula to solve a simple scenario

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have 838 rows of data which each have a calculated column showing me the duration from creation to resolution.

The average of all those rows duration is 63 hours.

I want to say if I move x rows up by y hours what would be my total average?

How do I work this out?

Thanks for all your help!!!!

Comment: Simply put, where do I start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current average is 63 hours. This means that the total of the number of hours in all the data is 838 * 63 = 52794 total hours.

If you increase x rows by y hours, the total number of hours will be 52794 + xy. Then the new average will be $\dfrac{52794 + xy}{838} = 63 + \dfrac{xy}{838}$.

Does that make sense?

Comment: it does, and your amazing! thank you!